# Adding special character to AEM Rich Text Editor

Tags: aem

I'm trying to add a special character on RTE. Basically, I need to add the [pbr](https://www.adonline.id.au/fonts/plant-breeders-webfont) icon on the RTE. I'm wondering if it's possible to add it since it is in .woff2, woff, .ttf, and .svg format. As far as I know only unicode values can be added but if it's possible please link me the documentation.

Comment: Were you able to add it?